# How to write Windows Search style query string parser?

Tags: c#, search, lexer

Using C# I'm trying to add a search capability to an application I work on but I'd like to write a search provider that I can use over and over that would take in the query string the user typed in and then parse it into a dictionary of results. The dictionary would just contain keyword and value. IE. Keyword "last" and Value "Simpson"

I'd like to allow the search field to accept plain strings, quoted strings, and parametered strings like the Windows Search does. It doesn't have to be extensive as Windows Search is. Obviously something has to parse the query string the user inputs and then something else interprets the parsed query string into a query for the data source.

How does someone go about writing a lexer or something that can parse the multiple variations a user could type in into a actually something useful? 
Are there any frameworks that can make this easier like specifying a keywords and parameters?
Basically what I'm looking for is some information on where to start on how to do this. I have no problem doing the actual work, I'm just lost as to where to start trying to do this. A plain string and quoted strings are easy to parse but parametered strings have been the curve ball that is confusing me.

```
Example of plain query strings:
- hello.txt
- one two three

Example of quoted strings:
- "one two"
- one "two three"

Example of parametered strings:
- last:simpson
- first:bart
- name:"Bart Simpson"
- name:"Bart Simpson" age:12
- hello name:"Bart Simpson" fart age:12
```

Comment: You'll need to either find Microsoft's search grammar or define your own. Once you have the grammar, create a parser for said grammar. Google for `parser generator c#`.